# Is there a quick way to add translation key to all locales

Tags: ruby-on-rails

There are translations in 5 languages in my app. Each language has one corresponding file. Adding new translation key in every one of them by hand is very inefficient. How do you solve this problem? Maybe someone has written script for or know Rails command for this purpose?

Answer (score 3):

You can manage this translations and keep all keys in sync between with this gem `i18n-tasks`. This gem also support auto fill missing keys.

```
i18n-tasks health
```

So all you had to do is add one key to one file, and auto fill missing keys in other files.

```
 i18n-tasks add-missing
```